# Package path for Python

Tags: python, package

I would like to use a package in `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/<this package>`. But from what I checked from `sys.path`, this package is not in the path, so Python uses the package in `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages` instead. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried `sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/")`? (Or perhaps, since it looks like it's defaulting to another folder, `sys.path = ["/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/"] + sys.path`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for one script/program only I would just add to the top of the script:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages')
```

If this happens more often then either remove the package from `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages` if you can, or set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable during login.